# Set background color in hex

Tags: javascript

How to set elements background color as hex value in JavaScript? `backgroundColor` method sets only in rgb.

`square.style.backgroundColor = input_color;` 
`input_color` is #123456, but in the source sets `rgb(18, 52, 86)`

Comment: Would you clarify? What specifically do you mean by "hex value" and "rgb"?

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals Huh? He means hex code for a color, and rgb is the same thing but like (255,255,255). What 'backgroundColor' method do you speak of OP?

Comment: @AaronKurtzhals just updated post

Comment: @thatidiotguy default, look in the post

Comment: When you say "in the source", what source do you mean? Is the problem that the color is wrong?

Comment: Why do you think setting the string `"#123456"` would not work? Of course, when reading the property you get back the normalized rgb-format.

Comment: Try setting your Color Format to: 'As authored' in the dev tools.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I have the same problem. I'm setting the color from a selected option to the corresponding select element via javascript. After Setting the background-color, the color in the html source is in rgb format. This works in most browsers... But unfortunately not in firefox.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the color of an element which is in `rgb` format then you can convert it  from `rgb` to `hex` format

```
function rgbToHex(col)
{
    if(col.charAt(0)=='r')
    {
        col=col.replace('rgb(','').replace(')','').split(',');
        var r=parseInt(col[0], 10).toString(16);
        var g=parseInt(col[1], 10).toString(16);
        var b=parseInt(col[2], 10).toString(16);
        r=r.length==1?'0'+r:r; g=g.length==1?'0'+g:g; b=b.length==1?'0'+b:b;
        var colHex='#'+r+g+b;
        return colHex;
    }
}
```

Call the function

```
var col=document.getElementById('myDiv').style.backgroundColor;
alert(rgbToHex(col)); // alerts hex value
```

[**Here is an example**](http://jsbin.com/otekon/5/edit).

Comment: I'm not sure how robust this is. Is the value that you read guaranteed to be in the rgb() format? If it can also be in hex, I would at least default to returning the argument (your function returns undefined in that case). And what if a browser decides to keep the stored value? Your code would try (and fail) to convert the string "red" into an rgb value.So while the idea is good, I don't think this is the best solution. (Of course, the "best" solution would require a robust method for getting the color components, and I'm not aware of that existing.)

Answer (score 2):

A better solution to your problem would be just to set the background color like this

```
square.style.backgroundColor = "rgb(12,34,56)";
```

Otherwise I would use Sheika's example

Answer (score 1):

Found something that should work:

```
document.getElementById('square').attributes['style'].textContent='background-color:'+ input_color
```

Comment: sounds like a solution but why you can't set this directly using backgroundColor property...?

Comment: looks like if you use backgroundColor property, the browser automatically formats it to rgb, but by setting it explicitly as textContent it will keep the format.

Answer (score -1):

Method `backgroundColor` [supports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-color) hex value and others too.
You can use `square.style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000'`.

Here is the code snippet that demonstrates it:

```js
document.getElementById('square').style.backgroundColor = '#FF0000';
```

```html
<div id="square" style="background-color: rgb(0, 255, 0); width: 50px; height: 50px"></div>
```

Answer (score -4):

If you want hex, you can set it as a string such as '#123456', or you can use hex numbers `rgb (0x12, 0x34, 0x56)`.

In other words, both square.style.backgroundColor = '#123456'; and square.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(18, 52, 86)'; work and have the exact same effect.

So the answer to your question: how to set it as a hex value, is answered in your question: you can put the hex value in a string and set it.

What you seem to mean is: How do I retrieve the value in hex? The problem you have is caused by the fact that the style is internally not a copy of what you set it to, so there is no guarantee what format it will be returned in. If you really need a copy of the string that you set it to, store that string in a variable at the same time as setting the style. Then retrieve that variable instead of reading the style attribute.

Comment: The question is: how to set it as hex using JS

Comment: I did already answer that, but I've added some text to make that more clear, but an answer to the question that he probably meant to ask.