# side menu appears -- div not moving

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have added a side menu layer to my HTML app taking refrence this link http://www.uiupdates.com/sidebar-menu-layer-with-jquery/.

When i press menu button & side menu appers. My following div class `"buttoncls_scrollableCenter" & "buttoncls_fotter"` is able to move right when menu appears .

But this div `"buttoncls_scrollable"` does not moves to the right when side menu appears.

How to make this div `"buttoncls_scrollable"` move when side menu appears ?

Code :--

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="height: 100%;">

<head>
<title>My item list </title>
<style>
body, html {
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
}

.div_wrapper {
 left:0px;
 z-index:100;
}
.div_layer {
 background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3e4046;
 position: absolute;
 width: 200px;
 height: 100%;
}
.div_layer ul {
 list-style-type: none;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}
.div_layer ul li {
border-bottom: 1px solid #dfdfdf;
overflow: hidden;
padding: 5px;
height: 33px;
color:white;
text-align:center;
}
.buttoncls {
 background:#767676;
 width:75px;
 height:25px;
 position:absolute;
 float:left;
 border:1px solid #000;
 cursor:pointer;
 color:#fff;
}

.input {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 0 2px;
}
.input input {
    display: block;
}
.imgtxt {
    margin: 0;
    font-family:arial;
    color:#DDDFED;
    font-size:15px;
}
#images {
    background-color: grey;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
div.scrollable {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}


div.scrollableMenu {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

div.scrollableCenter {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    padding-left: 4px;
    padding-top: 20px;
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

#center {
    background-color:#292B3B;
    position:absolute;
    top:115px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    bottom:20px;
}
#fotter {
    background-color:#CC99FF;
    text-align:center;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
    width:100%;
}
</style>


<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function menu_onclick() {

    var rig=$('.div_layer').position().left;
    if(rig == 0 )
    {


      $('.div_layer').animate({left:-this.width}, 300);

        $(".buttoncls_scrollable").animate({left:'0px'}, 300);
      $(".buttoncls_scrollableCenter").animate({left:'0px'}, 300);
      $(".buttoncls_fotter").animate({left:'0px'}, 300);
    }
    else
    {
        var center = this.width;

      $('.div_layer').animate({left:'0px'}, 300);

        $(".buttoncls_scrollable").animate({left:this.width}, 300);
        $(".buttoncls_scrollableCenter").animate({left:center}, 300);
        $(".buttoncls_fotter").animate({left:this.width}, 300);

    }

}


function doc_onload() {

    this.width = $('.div_layer').width();
    $('.div_layer').css('left',-this.width);
    this.rig = $('.div_layer').position().left;


};

//http://rickluna.com/wp/2012/10/setting-css-background-colors-via-javascript-rgb-triplet-vs-hex/

 function convertToHex(str){
    var raw = str.match(/(\d+)/g);
    var hexr = parseInt(raw[0]).toString(16);
    var hexg = parseInt(raw[1]).toString(16);
    var hexb = parseInt(raw[2]).toString(16);
        hexr = hexr.length == 1 ? '0' + hexr: hexr;
        hexg = hexg.length == 1 ? '0' + hexg: hexg;
        hexb = hexb.length == 1 ? '0' + hexb: hexb;
    var hex = '#' + hexr + hexg + hexb;
    return hex;
  }

//

function selectId(id) {
    //alert(id);

   if(id == "1")
   {

//alert('one');

    var div = document.getElementById('1');
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

    var div = document.getElementById('2');
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'black';

    var div = document.getElementById('3');
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'black';

   }


//http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712697/set-background-color-in-hex
//http://rickluna.com/wp/2012/10/setting-css-background-colors-via-javascript-rgb-triplet-vs-hex/
   if(id == "2")
   {
//alert('two');

    var div = document.getElementById('1');
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'black';

    var div = document.getElementById('2');
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'red';

    var div = document.getElementById('3');
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'black';

   }


   if(id == "3")
   {
//alert('three');

    var div = document.getElementById('1');
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'black';

    var div = document.getElementById('2');
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'black';

    var div = document.getElementById('3');
    div.style.backgroundColor =   'red';

   }

    $('.div_layer').animate({left:-this.width}, 300);

    var center = 250;

    $(".buttoncls_scrollable").animate({left:'100px'}, 300);
    $(".buttoncls_scrollableCenter").animate({left:'0px'}, 300);
    $(".buttoncls_fotter").animate({left:'0px'}, 300);

    //collaspe the menu
};

</script>

</head>

<body onload="doc_onload()">


   <div class="div_layer">
         <ul>
         <li onclick="selectId(this.id)" id="1">Fruits</li>
         <li onclick="selectId(this.id)" id="2">Automobile</li>
         <li onclick="selectId(this.id)" id="3">Cloth</li>

         </ul>
   </div>
    <div id="images" class="scrollable buttoncls_scrollable">

        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="http://www.shoredreams.net/wp-content/uploads/2014/02/show-menu-icon.png" onclick="menu_onclick()"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Menu</p>
        </div>

        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRTBRnn9Aqx74JvKyJ7Z5ydbXXuj8cIDVuOdJZUxb02Q2LWfJGP" onclick="alert('clicked')"  alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Normal Vegitable</p>
        </div>
        <div class="input">
            <input type="image" src="http://www.boldsky.com/img/2013/03/19-greenveggies.jpg" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" />
            <p class="imgtxt">Green Vegitable</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="center" class="scrollableCenter buttoncls_scrollableCenter">
        <div >
            <input type="image" src="http://t1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTMPmp8aVaovrd3AGj1_hL_GEXX1M4DJ-TTMJ34Vr622XeY_usu" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-top : 20px; padding-right : 100px; float:right;">brinjal</p>
        <hr/>
        </div>

        <div >
            <input type="image" src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/25/Cauliflower.JPG" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-top : 20px; padding-right : 100px; float:right;">cauliflower</p>
        <hr/>
        </div>

        <div >
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQJgt4i9ph9uQsS3JV940PBg-kwN1kkrKbC6FLYI6UhbxucEb91" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-top : 20px; padding-right : 100px; float:right;">tomato</p>
        <hr/>
        </div>

    <div >
            <input type="image" src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT-mwuxaqQeHXjoZzPUoee9Rvg8Jq-eCvo8H0EgEtapjfr6U4E3" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-top : 20px; padding-right : 100px; float:right;">ladyfinger</p>
        <hr/>
        </div>

    <div >
            <input type="image" src="http://t2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQRxXUO2stKHLyET_rXpxOuLp67qc1IzlBcJGke5jYoGPeRZpnO" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-top : 20px; padding-right : 100px; float:right;">radish</p>
        <hr/>
        </div>

    <div >
            <input type="image" src="http://t3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcT2zCeG621TSX1YmcsT9DPLaQJkdVwdYk_n-eWECCa8NTtXR0LFeQ" onclick="alert('clicked')" alt="Bulb pop up" width="80" height="48" hspace="10" vspace="6"/>
            <p class="imgtxt" style="padding-top : 20px; padding-right : 100px; float:right;">ginger</p>
        <hr/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="buttoncls_fotter" id="fotter">List of Items</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Actual Html page:--
[image]

side Menu appears, top div is not moving :--
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to absolutely position your `buttoncls_scrollable`:

```
div.scrollable {
    position: absolute;
    right:0;
    left:0;
}
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/zkkfsL9c/)

If you also change your `#fotter` to have `right:0` instead of `width:100%;` it will fix your issue with the horizontal scrollbar appearing when the side menu shows

Answer (score 0):

why not using jquery? it will be very simple.
there is more than one way to do it but you can for example use the Jquery [`click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) function to do the action and to use Jquery [`addClass()`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) function to give the 'body' (or other 'wrap all' element) a class to affect all his children after click - new position for the menu and for the new div (div that wrap all the element except of the menu itself). on the HTML, add a div that will wrap all the elements except of the menu itself and add to the input image a class or id to avoid conflict, for example add a id (id="menu_button") and call it with jquery:

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#menu_button').click(function(){
        if ($('body').hasClass('show')){    
            $('body').removeClass('show');  
        }
        else {
            $('body').addClass('show')
        }
    });
});
```

on CSS, you need to add the new div wrap. add `left: 200px;` (the width of the menu) to hide the menu fully when it's not need be displayed. add `z-index: 1;` (you can use higher value as long as it will be higher the all the rest element that needs to be below). for make them menu above the other elements. add new class with `left: 0;` to bring the menu to the position it needs to be after click. you can use CSS3 [`transition`](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp) for better show.

CSS:

```
.content_wrap
{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
}

.show .content_wrap
{
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
}

.div_layer
{
     background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #3e4046;
     position: absolute;
     left: -200px;
     width: 200px;
     height: 100%;
     z-index: 1;
}

.show .div_layer
{
    left: 0;   
}

.content_wrap, .div_layer
{
     -webkit-transition: 1s;
     -moz-transition: 1s;
     transition: 1s;   
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/6dgbp5dh/1/