# changing colour definition - Traffic Light Script

Tags: javascript, html, hex, rgb

so I am trying to create a script in HTML and JavaScript that has a traffic light which changes when a button is presses. I have all the HTML sorted out, but the if /else statement is playing up on me.

Here is the code as it stands:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<table border="10px" style="background-color: #000000">
<tr>
<td width="30px" height="30px" style="background-color: #000000" id="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30px" height="30px" style="background-color: #ecec54" id="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30px" height="30px" style="background-color: #01db01" id="3"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<p id="temp">1234567890</p>

<button type="button" onclick=changeLights()>Change Lights</button>

</body>
<script>
var lightInfo = ["1","2","3"]

function changeLights() {
 var oneState = document.getElementById(lightInfo[0]).getAttribute("style")
 var twoState = document.getElementById(lightInfo[1]).getAttribute("style")
 var threeState = document.getElementById(lightInfo[2]).getAttribute("style")
 document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = oneState
 if (oneState === "background-color: #000000") {
  document.getElementById(lightInfo[0]).style.backgroundColor = "#f00000";
 } 
 else {
  document.getElementById(lightInfo[0]).style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
 }
}
</script>
</html>
```

PS. The paragraph is just a temporary debugging thing.

So I want the code to get the hexadecimal colour for each data cell to use in the if statement, which works to change the top light from black to red (since I get the hexadecimal for black, which is #000000). However, when I try repeat the process, the colour for the red data cell comes out as some other format (rgb(240,0,0)), which makes the if statement fail and the code break. Is there ay way to make sure the colour is given in a hexadecimal format?

Answer (score 0):

So if you wanted to get the `hex` value in JavaScript, you'd have to make a separate function [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13712697/set-background-color-in-hex). But, an easier way to solve your problem, is just specify the `hex` and the `rgb` for the black color in your if statement.

**JS**

```
if (oneState === "background-color: #000000" || oneState === "background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);") {
  //Do stuff
}
```

```js
var lightInfo = ["1","2","3"]

function changeLights() {
 var oneState = document.getElementById(lightInfo[0]).getAttribute("style")
 var twoState = document.getElementById(lightInfo[1]).getAttribute("style")
 var threeState = document.getElementById(lightInfo[2]).getAttribute("style")
 document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = oneState;
 if (oneState === "background-color: #000000" || oneState === "background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);") {
  document.getElementById(lightInfo[0]).style.backgroundColor = "#FF0000";
 } 
 else {
  document.getElementById(lightInfo[0]).style.backgroundColor = "#000000";
 }
}
```

```html
<table border="10px" style="background-color: #000000">
<tr>
<td width="30px" height="30px" style="background-color: #000000" id="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30px" height="30px" style="background-color: #ecec54" id="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30px" height="30px" style="background-color: #01db01" id="3"></td>
</tr>
</table>

<p id="temp">1234567890</p>

<button type="button" onclick=changeLights()>Change Lights</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I may be going off topic here, but why dont you do this using css classes?

eg: have css:

```
.black {
  background-color: #000000;
}

.red {
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.yellow {
   background-color: #ecec54;
}

.green {
    background-color: #01db01;
 }
```

And update your html to be:

```
<table border="10px" class="black">
<tr>
<td width="30px" height="30px" class="black" id="1"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30px" height="30px" class="yellow" id="2"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="30px" height="30px" class="green" id="3"></td>
```

And update your javascript to be:

```
var lightInfo = ["1","2","3"]

function changeLights() {
    var oneState = document.getElementById(lightInfo[0]).className
    var twoState = document.getElementById(lightInfo[1]).className
    var threeState = document.getElementById(lightInfo[2]).className
    document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = oneState
    if (oneState.indexOf('black') > -1) {
        document.getElementById(lightInfo[0]).className.replace('black','');
        document.getElementById(lightInfo[0]).className += ' red';
    } 
    else {
        document.getElementById(lightInfo[0]).className.replace('red','');
        document.getElementById(lightInfo[0]).className += ' black';
    }
}
```

This might be a better approach, as in more robust code in comparison.